# Xamarin-UItest: System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements

Tags: xamarin.uitest

I am trying to `Xamarin.uiTest` to automate an application and I got this error in very initial stage.

> System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements

**Code: AppInitializer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.UITest;
using Xamarin.UITest.Queries;

namespace MyXamarinApp1_Test1
{
public class AppInitializer
    {
        public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
        {
            if (platform == Platform.Android)
            {
                return ConfigureApp
                    .Android
                    //.InstalledApp("com.companyname.MyXamarinApp1")
                    .ApkFile("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\com.companyname.MyXamarinApp1.apk")
             .StartApp();
            }

            return ConfigureApp
                .iOS.StartApp();
        }
    }
}
```

**Code: Test.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Xamarin.UITest;
using Xamarin.UITest.Queries;

namespace UITest1
{
    [TestFixture(Platform.Android)]
    [TestFixture(Platform.iOS)]
    public class Tests
    {
        IApp app;
        Platform platform;

        public Tests(Platform platform)
        {
            this.platform = platform;
        }

    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest()
    {
        app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);
    }

    [Test]
    public void AppLaunches()
    {
        app.Screenshot("First screen.");
    }
}
```

Any idea to resolve the issue is appreciated.

I am using the signed app, could it be an issue.

Xamarin version : 2.0.3
Nunit : 2.6.4

Answer (score 0):

try downgrading or upgrading it to Xamarin 2.2.1 or less and try cleaning solution or delete debug folder and build and run the command in fresh command line window, it may fix.. not 100% sure